# Why would we want to make a function recursive when it has a mutex lock?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524120/462608

> If you want to call functions recursively, which lock the same mutex, then they either
>   have to use one recursive mutex, or
>   have to unlock and lock the same non-recursive mutex again and again (beware of concurrent threads!), or
>   have to somehow annotate which mutexes they already locked (simulating recursive   ownership/mutexes).

Can in any case this be a "sensible" design decision to make function recursive which already has a mutex lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to paxdiablo's exmaple using an actual recursive funciotn, don't forget that using a mutex recursively doesn't necessarily mean that the functions involved are recursive. I've found use for recursive mutexes for dealing with a situation where you have complex operations which need to be atomic with respect to some data structure, with those complex operations rely on more fundamental operations that still need to use the mutex since the fundamental operations can be used on their own as well.  An example might be something like the following (note that the code is illustrative only - it doesn't use proper error handling or transactional techniques that might really be necessary when dealing with accounts and logs):

```
struct account
{
    mutex mux;

    int balance;

    // other important stuff...

    FILE* transaction_log;
};

void write_timestamp( FILE*);


// "fundamental" operation to write to transaction log
void log_info( struct account* account, char* logmsg)
{
    mutex_acquire( &account->mux);

    write_timestamp( account->transaction_log);
    fputs( logmsg, account->transaction_log);

    mutex_release( &account->mux);
}


// "composed" operation that uses the fundamental operation.
//  This relies on the mutex being recursive
void update_balance( struct account* account, int amount)
{
    mutex_acquire( &account->mux);

    int new_balance = account->balance + amount;

    char msg[MAX_MSG_LEN];
    snprintf( msg, sizeof(msg), "update_balance: %d, %d, %d", account->balance, amount, new_balance);

    // the following call will acquire the mutex recursively
    log_info( account, msg);

    account->balance = new_balance;

    mutex_release( &account->mux);
}
```

To do something more or less equivalent without recursive mutexes means that the code would need to take care not to reacquire the mutex if it already held it.  One option is to add some sort of flag (or thread ID) to the data structure to indicate if the mutex is already held.  In this case, you're essentially implementing recursive mutexes - a trickier bit of work than it might seem at first to get right.  An alternative is to pass a flag indicating you already acquired the mutex to functions as a parameter (easier to implement and get right) or simply have even more fundamental operations that assume the mutex is already acquired and call those from the higher level functions that take on the responsibility of acquiring the mutex:

```
// "fundamental" operation to write to transaction log
//  this version assumes that the lock is already held
static
void log_info_nolock( struct account* account, char* log msg)
{
    write_timestamp( account->transaction_log);
    fputs( logmsg, account->transaction_log);
}


// "public" version of the log_info() function that
//      acquires the  mutex
void log_info( struct account* account, char* logmsg)
{
    mutex_acquire( &account->mux);
    log_info_nolock( account, logmsg);    
    mutex_release( &account->mux);
}


// "composed operation that uses the fundamental operation
//      since this function acquires the mutex, it much call the
//      "nolock" version of the log_info() function
void update_balance( int amount)
{
    mutex_acquire( &account->mux);

    int new_balance = account->balance + amount;

    char msg[MAX_MSG_LEN];
    snprintf( msg, sizeof(msg), "update_balance: %d, %d, %d", account->balance, amount, new_balance);

    // the following call assumes the lock is already acquired
    log_info_nolock( account, msg);

    account->balance = new_balance;

    mutex_release( &account->mux);
}
```

Comment: In production code, it is very likely that log_info cannot be a separate transaction, but must be part of a larger transaction.  Indeed, if you did not have recursive locks, and were forced to write the second version, you would have to stop and think - "what is the invariant of the account"?  And you would see that an invariant is that the in-memory view of the account should be the same as the transactional log view.  Only when holding the lock can this invariant be broken. It follows that log_info can't be a transaction of its own.

Comment: You just "proved" with your example that there is no need for recursive mutexes in these kind of scenarios. It should always be possible with relatively little effort to refactor the code to just not lock recursively. So the answer once again to OP's question is "No, you can always refactor your code in such a way to not need to call a function that will lock the same mutex again."

Answer (score 2):

Well, *one* possibility is that the resource you're using lends itself naturally to recursive algorithms.

Think of searching a binary tree, while preventing everyone else from using (especially modifying) the tree out with a mutex.

If you use a recursive mutex, you can simply have one function `search()` that you pass the root node in to. It then recursively calls itself as per a normal binary tree search but the first thing it does in that function is to lock the mutex (while this *looks* like Python, that's really just because Python is an ideal basis for pseudo-code):

```
def search (haystack, mutex, needle):
    lock mutex recursively

    if haystack == NULL:
        unlock mutex and return NULL

    if haystack.payload == needle:
        unlock mutex and return haystack

    if haystack.payload > needle:
        found = search (haystack.left, mutex, needle)
    else:
        found = search (haystack.right, mutex, needle)

    unlock mutex and return found
```

The alternative is to separate the mutex lock and search into two *separate* functions like `search()` (public) and `search_while_locked()` (most likely private):

```
def private search_while_locked (haystack, needle):
    if haystack == NULL:
        return NULL

    if haystack.payload == needle:
        return haystack

    if haystack.payload > needle:
        return search_while_locked (haystack.left, needle)

    return search_while_locked (haystack.right, needle)

def search (haystack, mutex, needle):
    lock mutex non-recursively

    found = search_while_locked (haystack.right, needle)

    unlock mutex and return found
```

While that *sort* of defeats the elegance of the recursive solution, I actually prefer it since it reduces the amount of work that needs to be done (however small that work is, it's still work).

And languages that lend themselves easily to public/private functions can encapsulate the details well. The *user* of your class has no knowledge (or need of knowledge) as to how you do things *within* your class, they just call the public API.

Your *own* functions, however, have access to all the non-public stuff as well as full knowledge as to what locks need to be in place for certain operations.

---

Another possibility is very much related to that but *without* being recursive.

Think of *any* useful operation you may want users to perform on your data which requires that no-one else be using it during that time. So far, you have just the classic case for a non-recursive mutex. For example, clearing all of the entries out of a queue:

```
def clearQueue():
    lock mutex
    while myQueue.first <> null:
        myQueue.pop()
    unlock mutex
```

*Now* let's say you find that rather useful and want to call it from your destructor, which *already* locks the mutex:

```
def destructor():
    lock mutex
    clearQueue()
    doSomethingElseNeedingLock()
    unlock mutex
```

Obviously, with a non-recursive mutex, that's going to lock up on the first line of `clearQueue` after your destructor calls it, which may be one reason why you'd want a recursive mutex.

You *could* use the afore-mentioned method of providing a locking public function and a non-locking private one:

```
def clearQueueLocked():
    while myQueue.first <> null:
        myQueue.pop()

def clearQueue():
    lock mutex
    clearQueueLocked():
    unlock mutex

def destructor():
    lock mutex
    clearQueueLocked():
    doSomethingElseNeedingLock()
    unlock mutex and return
```

However, if there are a substantial number of these public/private function pairs, it may get a little messy.

Comment: *"Think of searching a binary tree, while locking everyone else out with a mutex."* I meant a binary search tree "can" be written non-recursively too. and I didn't understand *"while locking everyone else out with a mutex."*

Comment: Yes, it can be done iteratively, but it's much more _natural_ as a recursive solution. And I meant what it says. If you don't want the tree changing while you're searching, you lock it. Try however not to fixate on the specific case since it's rather contrived. The answer, however, is still valid. Any case where a recursive solution seems more natural but requires a resource lock may be one reason why you'd want a recursive mutex.

Comment: also, in the OP it is mentioned *"beware of concurrent threads!"*. Please explain that in this context.

Comment: @Anisha, I'm not sure why they were suggesting that option since it full of holes. Presumably they meant unlock it before making the recursive call (which will then relock it). However, that is _not_ safe since another thread can steal the mutex from you during the unlock-recur-lock time (hence the warning). Basic rule of mutexes: don't release them if you haven't got your resource in a consistent state, or if you don't want someone else to change it yet.

Comment: The second implementation is both more readable, less obfuscated, and faster.  After years of writing multi threaded code, I would never let the first version through a code review. Recursive locks always leads to not-fully-thought-out code, like the first version. The first version would make sense if there were mutexes per level in the tree.  In which case a fairly special locking protocol is needed, but where parallel searches will be possible.

Comment: I came here to make sense of the quote from the original question. But I just found a demonstration (using an example) how the quote is just non-sensical. What we see above is a natural and elegant way to refactor the bad code to not need recursive locking (even when the solution is natural to express recursively - especially so when we think of expressing this using some functional programming language with tail recursion elimination).