# Why there is a deadlock when thread tried to grab same spinlock twice?

Tags: multithreading, spinlock

Could someone explain to me why there will be a deadlock when one thread tries to grab same spinlock twice ? (Assuming that spinlock is non-recursive)

Regular spinlock usage:

```
lock = false; 
while(acquiring_lock(lock)) {} //sit in the loop and wait for lock to become available
....critical section....
release_lock(lock);
```

However, I don't understand why second call to `acquiring_lock(lock)` would cause deadlock ?

Comment: Hard to guess what kind of threading library you are using.  But if you get deadlock then the common diagnostic would be that the lock is not re-entrant.  That's not unusual.

Comment: @HansPassant this is just a theoretical question. Though, I see your point and will correct the question

Comment: What is the specification of the acquiring_lock() function? Will it return true if the lock is acquired? or will it return false? does it block until it has acquired the lock?

Comment: @Xantix Since I am new to multitasking, I am assuming that "blocked" means it will just wait(or in case of mutex - go to sleep) and if it is non-blocking spinlock, it will return 1 or 0 ?  Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this question really depends on threading library in question, as well as the specification of the different functions. So, let's consider a few possibilities.

Locking mechanisms may be [blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) or nonblocking as well as [re-entrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312259/what-is-the-re-entrant-lock-and-concept-in-general) and not re-entrant.

```
/** 
* This function performs a busy wait, blocking until it acquires the lock
* This is not re-entrant.
**/
void blocking_acquire_lock(bool thingToLock);
```

If you try using the preceding function, your code will deadlock. This is because the thread will not continue execution until it has acquired the lock. You would not use this in the condition position of a while loop, since it does not return a bool. Secondly, It is not re-entrant meaning if you attempt to re-acquire the lock after having acquired it even with the same thread, it will continue to wait for the lock to be released.

```
/** 
* This function performs a non-blocking busy wait, blocking for up to X milleseconds, 
* until it acquires the lock. This is not re-entrant.
* returns true if lock acquired, false if lock not acquired
**/
bool non_blocking_acquire_lock(bool thingToLock, int timeoutInMilliseconds);
```

This version makes some sense to use in a while loop. You can try to get acquire a lock, but if it does not have success within an allotted time, you can decide what to do. Perhaps, you will decide to work on something else for a while and then re-try to acquire the lock.

Since it is not re-entrant, it will not allow the same thread to acquire it twice, without first releasing it. Due to this, your code will deadlock.

Here is one last example which will seem to deadlock on your code.

```
/** 
* This function performs a non-blocking busy wait, blocking for up to X milleseconds, 
* until it acquires the lock. This is re-entrant.
* returns true if lock acquired, false if lock not acquired
**/
bool non_blocking_reentrant_acquire_lock(bool thingToLock, int timeoutInMilliseconds);
```

This lock is re-entrant, so if a thread owns the lock, it can re-acquire it. However, if you use this inside of a while loop like the following, you will notice something interesting.

```
my_lock = false; 
while(acquiring_lock(my_lock, 1000)) { ; }
    ....critical section....
release_lock(lock);
```

Since the lock returns true if it acquires the lock within 1 second, and this is the only thread, it should likely acquire the lock without problem. It returns true. In which case, it will stay in the while loop. The while loop is empty, so it immediately tries re-acquiring the lock.

Since it is re-entrant, I would expect it to continually succeed. It will continue to successfully re-acquire the lock, and never get past the while loop.

I would expect the following code with an extra "!" to be what you intended.

```
my_lock = false; 
while( !acquiring_lock(my_lock, 1000)) { ; }
    ....critical section....
release_lock(lock);
```

This version, will actually stop trying to acquire the lock, i.e. exit the while loop, once it has acquired the lock.

Comment: WOW !!! Thank your for taking time to explain all of this to me.